# Adobe DTM Mobile Tracking Rules

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm trying to create a DTM event rule that triggers an event at the start of a form, and then a different event for each step of the process (three steps total).

The event rule I create is setup like so:

[image]

The thought is to isolate the device type and then create individual rules associated to each step of the process, but the rule doesn't seem to be working. I testing this by using a useragent plugin for Chrome.

If this isn't the right approach or isn't going to work, I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: Based on ss, you have a link on your page along the lines of this: `<a className="Request Info" href="somepage.html">some page</a>`  and the rule is supposed to trigger when you click on it. Are you sure this is right? I am skeptical about your link having an attribute named `className` with a value like this..Please post the actual html element you are trying to target.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, but I'm going to keep going with it to be certain. First you definitely pointed out my stupidity and mistake.

`<a href="/wgu/inquiry_form-b" class="btn--yellow--arrow"> "Request Info"</a>`

The `className` is completely wrong. I'm trying to specifically target the "Request Info" button for this particular rule.

Comment: @Brando - is the form a SPA or do you have multiple pages?

Comment: @MarkStringham it's an SPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay in your comment you said you are trying to trigger the rule based on this link:

`<a href="/wgu/inquiry_form-b" class="btn--yellow--arrow"> "Request Info"</a>`

Here is an example of what I *think* you are attempting to do, based on what you have shown so far.

**Event Type:** `click`

**Element Tag Or Selector:** `a`

Enable **Manually assign properties & attributes**

Add the follow **Propery** and **Value** entries:

**Property:** `innerText`  **Value**(*enable regex*)**:** `\bRequest Info\b`

*Note:The above is regex with word boundaries because DTM does not properly store/output quotes in this field so this is next best thing.*

**Property:** `pathname` **Value:** `/wgu/inquiry_form-b`

*Screenshot:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an idea:

Step 1: Check to see if form exists on page load
Step 2: if form exists. Set cookie to “start” and fire start event
Step 3: On click of form 1 submit, check for cookie value. If set to start (previous action), set cookie to form 1 submit and fire form 1 event.
Step 4: Repeat until confirmation page and clear cookie upon submission

This should only require event based rules, a cookie for current state and events for each step in the funnel.

Just a something to try.
Mark

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. My iPhone wasn’t playing nice 

Comment: Thanks for the idea, a great one, but a little out of the scope or length of work really needed for this particular piece of the project. Right now I only care about the success events. The site is planning on changing within the next few months or so anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If this is part of a spa and you just want to trigger your rule for each step, I would suggest using an Event rule, but instead of a click use `pushState or hashchange`. This will trigger each time the hash in your url changes, so that you can fire a page view on each step or capture values as needed. You can also filter your criteria to hash to only include/exclude specific hashes. Just make sure that if your site has multiple spas included that might have the same hashes that you specify your path as well. I use this for SPAs across some different sites and its worked beautifully.

**EDIT

[image: pushState]

This is a basic rule I have set up on a reservation path. The URL is `/reserve.html`, with hashes like: `details`, `booking`, `review`, and `confirmed`. This rule fires on every hash but `/reserve.html#confirmed` which has a different rule with conversion tags and pixels.

Comment: Hmm....Never really tried using the `pushState` or `hashchange` might be a good test run with a few other form projects I'm working on. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm going to have to revisit this topic. I think it's going to be much more relevant in my scenario, but it's early in the process. Do you have a working example that I could take a look at? Like a URL process to review?

Comment: I added a screenshot with some details. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Tried the `pushState` or `hashchange` - for my setup it won't work since there are no hashes; direct call rules might be the best route in my situation. Each step would need to trigger a separate event. (e.g. step 1 - event 1, step 2 - event 2)